# How to Create SharePoint Designer Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am very new to SharePoint Designer and have a requirement to create a workflow using SP Designer (this will be my very first workflow using designer)

There are 2 Default SharePoint List

1. Custom List
2. Task List

**Requirement is when an item is created in List (1) the workflow should trigger or Start a Task from the Task List (2).**

Can someone enlighten me on how to achieve this?

**More Info**

---

I have already created a Custom List as "A" And a task List as "B" what am trying to achieve here is when an item is created in Custom List "A" it should start a workflow and use the Task List "B" I started to follow the steps from the link you gave me and now wondering where in the workflow do i specify/ point the "Task List B"

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom list workflow and add workflow action to start task a task in Task list. Refer below for more details:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/understanding-task-actions-in-sharepoint-designer

Comment: I have already created a Custom List as "A" And a task List as "B"
what am trying to achieve here is when an item is created in Custom List "A" it should start a workflow and use the Task List "B" 

I started to follow the steps from the link you gave me and now wondering where in the workflow do i specify/ point the "Task List B"

Comment: Go to workflow settings and there you have the option to associate history and task list.

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose the action create list item. After adding that, it would look something 
   like this:
   Create item in **this list** (Output to Variable: create)
2. Click on "this list" and select your Task list under the "Data source".